# HTMLUNIT getformbyname with no form name specified in the website

Tags: java, xpath, htmlunit

I'm trying to clcik a button on a website using HTMLUNIT i followed this tutorial http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html but it requires a form name. The website I'm trying to do has this page source.

```
<form method="post" action="doDelete">
     Are you sure you want to delete 'Apple?'?
 <input name="Submit" value="Yes" class="submit-button" type="submit" />
 </form>
```

I'm trying to click the "Yes" button validation box on the webpage.(Delete Valdation) As you can see there is no form name supplied. Here is my code.

```
 final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://ma.some-site.com:8080/user/mike/delete");



        List<HtmlForm> formlist = (List<HtmlForm>) page1.getForms();
       System.out.println(formlist.toString());

        final HtmlForm form = page1.getFormByName("myform"); <---Problem here
       final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("Submit");
       button.click();
        webClient.closeAllWindows();
```

I tried this but does not work

```
  final HtmlForm form =   page1.getFormByName(formlist.get(1).getLocalName());
```

I believe you can use xpath to find the form name?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can get this element by XPath this way:

```
final HtmlForm form = page1.getFirstByXPath("//form[@action='doDelete']");
```

Of course, if you have more elements with that action you should properly set the XPath to select the element you expect to get. The method [getFirstByXPath](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomNode.html#getFirstByXPath(java.lang.String)) will return only one of all the matching results. If you want to get many results and then do further processing then you should go for method [getByXPath](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomNode.html#getByXPath(java.lang.String)).

Let me know how that works.

Comment: in this how would i add if action in form action = /dialog/oauth/read